# Passing token and json as query parameters with curl

Tags: rest, curl

I have a URL like below that I use for query

```
http://<ip>:<port>/api/test/computers?token=a124af&criteria={"and":[["name","=","comp_name"]]}
```

I was writing a script for this and using curl to download the results from the url. But I am not able to get curl to work. Here is what i tried

```
curl http://<ip>:<port>/api/test/computers?token=a124af&criteria={"and":[["name","=","comp_name"]]}
```

-- This runs curl http://:/api/test/computers?token=a124af in background mode.

I know I can pass json data like curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '' . But in this case I have a mix of json as well as other data. How can i achieve that? this does not seem to work

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{"and":[["name","=","comp_name"]]}" "http://<ip>:<port>/api/test/computers?token=a124af&criteria="
```